# Gradle, Is there a way to alias namspace of dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to use my custom library which I forked from the opensource. I use jitpack to pull dependency from my github repo. The problem is that, the namespace has been changed to

> "com.github.user.Repo:module-name:version"

and I will have to replace this namespace to entire project which is a really hard work. so is there a way to alias namespace from "com.github.user.Repo:module-name:version" to "org.opensource:module-name:version"

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to alias anything, while configuring `MavenPublication`; for GitHub [example](https://github.com/syslogic/androidx-colorpicker/blob/master/library/build.gradle#L147):

```
group = 'io.syslogic'
version = '1.0.0'

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = group
                artifactId = 'androidx-colorpicker'
                from components.getByName('release')
                version = version_name
            }
        }
    }
}
```